# Disable creation of .orc.crc file

Tags: java, orc

I am working with the apache orc-core java api. I have noticed a couple of things and was wondering if there are options to control them

- Does not overwrite files. The call to `OrcFile.createWriter` fails if the specified file already exists. Is there an option to get it to overwrite by default?
- Generates `.crc` files. If I write to a file called `test.orc` the program also creates a file called `.test.orc.crc`. Is there an option to disable this?

I know I can work around both of these simply by deleting the relevant files in the code. Was just wondering if there was a "proper" way.